# Visual Studio 2021 "A project with an Output Type of Class library cannot be started directly"

Tags: debugging, output

Very new to Visual Studio. I am just trying to run a simple hello world but I can't get past the debugging. I believe there's probably something wrong with the Output type but no matter what I choose I still get an error message and there aren't that many other settings I can change.

"in order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project" I honestly don't know how to interpret this. What executable project?

[Error message with class library as output type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHkZh.png)

I think the other output types don't apply anyway as it's not a windows application or console application. I have also tried right-clicking on project and selecting "Set as startup project" but I still get the same message.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, Visual Studio 2021 does not exist, this could be a reason. This said, the error message exactly gives the explanation and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your code this could be a shot in the dark - but lets try.

When creating a new project, if you expect to create a simple console application that runs, then select "Console App" from the Wizard in Visual Studio.

A class library is, at it says, a library. Somewhere information can be stored and looked at by other projects\files.

It could be a place for all your logic, all your classes, whatever - but the invocation of any item in the class library is done from a different project which has a runtime.

If your trying do debug an existing project, then i guess there is references to other projects within your solution as well. Right click on what should be your "main point of entry", and select "Set as startup project".

[image: Visual Studio]

---

If this doesnt help, then please provide more details \ screenshots of how your project is setup and what your trying to achieve.

Comment: I actually tried that but it didn't work. Turns out my output type was in fact wrong and my little hello world was a console application. not a class library. I still don't understand the difference between the windows, console and class type outputs though. Anyway, I changed the startup object to  the class object and it did the trick. Thank you!!!

Comment: Great! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my output type was in fact wrong and my little hello world was a console application. not a class library. I still don't understand the difference between the windows, console and class type outputs though. Anyway, I changed the startup object to the class object and it did the trick.